# Pretty alternative to JProgressBar?

Tags: java, user-interface, jprogressbar

I'd like a nice progress bar for long running processes. Are there any pretty alternatives to JProgressBar out there, specifically for indeterminate processes?

I'm thinking of Web-2.0-looking twirls, spinning wheels, what have you.

Imaginary bonus points for no cost, LGPL-licensed stuff. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might like to [wait with style](http://www.jroller.com/gfx/entry/wait_with_style_in_swing) ;)

Here's a WebStart [demo app](http://www.progx.org/users/Gfx/apps/InfiniteProgressDemo.jnlp)

Here's a screen shot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [progx.org](http://www.progx.org/users/Gfx/waitwithstyle2.png))</sub>

Comment: That was the one I was looking for :)

Comment: Haha, yeah - I remember playing around with it a while back and so knew exactly what to search for :)  Still, I like your option aswell - it seems a bit more versatile.

Comment: The site is no longer available

Comment: RIP my sweet prince.

Comment: You may want to update your answer. That link is no longer safe.