# Creating a nice "LOADING..." animation

Tags: java, animation, loading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pretty alternative to JProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531831/pretty-alternative-to-jprogressbar)

I have a process which takes several seconds to load, and I want to create an animation in Java Swing until it finishes loading.

I'd like to avoid using a typical ProgressBar and use a nice modern infinite progress like this one

[image: infinite progress]

I'm aware of similar questions but this is strictly Java Swing related.
Is there any library or example for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/531831/505722

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend using the glasspane for this type of activity.  The steps involved are:

- Create a `JComponent` with `BorderLayout`.  Add a `JLabel` to the `CENTER` which includes the animated .gif icon of your choice.
- (Optional) Override the `paint(Graphics)` method to make your GUI appear greyed out (or whited out).  To achieve this you need to draw a filled rectangle the size of the component, filling the rectangle with a semi-transparent Color.
- Add the component as the glasspane of your application's root frame.

Comment: +1 Good merge candidate for the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531831/pretty-alternative-to-jprogressbar).

Comment: adding a small code example?

Answer (score 44):

Just use a [`ImageIcon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) for this task, **it automatically animates gifs**. The code below produced this screenshot (*the `ajax-loader.gif` was downloaded from http://www.ajaxload.info/*):

[image: screenshot]

### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("ajax-loader.gif");
    frame.add(new JLabel("loading... ", loading, JLabel.CENTER));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Doh, didn't check for dups :P

Comment: Thanks for the code. Sorry for dup posting!

Comment: how about hiding window menus and making it transparent? I think that's what he meant and not simply showing an icon inside a window.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it's possible. You can use the tool [AjaxLoad](http://www.ajaxload.info/) to generate an animated image, which can be used in any image/html container.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to share their reason?  Given the lack of information in the question, this seems a valid answer.

Comment: Not the down-voter, but probably won't work in a Swing component, which supports limited HTML but not Javascript. Possible merge candidate for the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531831/pretty-alternative-to-jprogressbar).

Comment: I'm skeptic about this answer, showing some working code might be appropriate.