# "\n" newline and %n does not work to begin newline

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I was putting simple loading animation to my previous code but I can't fine a way to begin new line when its showing the result.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Max");

ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("ajax-loader.gif");
frame.add(new JLabel("Processing to Result \n Result of Maximum is : "+max, loading,
                                                                       JLabel.CENTER));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

I also try to use newline and %n but both does not work.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E05P5.jpg

screenshot

Comment: How did you add the circular progress bar ? I am curious to know :)

Comment: oh...

I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634402/creating-a-nice-loading-animation

Comment: So basically it is a GIF

Comment: @KashamaShinn I found something: http://www.jroller.com/gfx/date/20050215

Comment: @LittleChild yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to add new line to `JLabel` without `HTML` tags.

You should do something like that:

```
frame.add(new JLabel("<html>Processing to Result <br> Result of Maximum is :" + max + 
           "</html>", loading,JLabel.CENTER));
```

If you want, you can switch to [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/), it does support that without `HTML` tags :)

Comment: Thank it work now.

one more thing, do you know how to make it a better look?

like: Loading animation showing 5sec then showing the result. Very appreciate for you answer. Thank again.

Answer (score 2):

A JLabel by default does not do any formatting. However you can use simply HTML tags to achieve what you want:

```
String label = "<html>Processing to Result<br>Result of Maximum is : "+max + "</html>;
frame.add(new JLabel(label, loading, JLabel.CENTER));
```

Comment: Thank it work now. one more thing, do you know how to make it a better look? like: Loading animation showing 5sec then showing the result. Very appreciate for you answer. Thank again.