# Dialog with swingworker is a chicken/egg

Tags: java, swingworker

I am trying to follow the Java best practices by not doing long tasks on the main thread (EDT). So I am planning to use a swingWorker with Modal Dialog. This way the modal dialog blocks the user for doing anything until that task is done and I can update status on the dialog while the process is taking place.

Now the problem is that with the modal dialog, it not only blocks the user but also nothing after setVisible gets called

So if I do

```
dialog.setVisible(true);
new SwingWorkerTask().execute(); //This does not get called
```

and if I do

```
new SwingWorkerTask().execute();
dialog.setVisible(true); // Well what the point of setting visible after the fact.
```

So How do I block user action and show a dialog while task is taking place?

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen any application that does this? Does your e-mail client pop up a dialog that prevents you from doing anything while it checks for mail? Does your database GUI block you with a dialog while running a query? Check what common applications do when they run long tasks, and follow their lead.

Comment: Hint: spent a bit more time on formatting your source code ;-)

Comment: The [JavaDoc of `SwingWorker#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get--) fortunately describes exactly your application case. Your second snippet is the right one: You **first** start the SwingWorker, and **then** make the dialog visible. Notice that this is usually done e.g. in some `actionPerformed` method due to some button click. This already *is* executed on the EDT. The `execute` call will spawn the background thread, and make the dialog visible to prevent further interaction.

Comment: How do you know your 2nd example is not working? doInBackground() method should be invoked.

Comment: (Side note: I always wondered what would happen if the `SwingWorker#execute` finished **so** fast that it was `done` **before** the next line of code was executed. In this case, the proposed solution with the modal dialog would cause the *dialog to remain open forever*. But digging through `SwingWorker#getWorkersExecutorService` is a bit painfull, and I just *hope* that this is somehow avoided internally)

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have seen the applications and thus my question. I was wondering how they do it. I know it is doable. I am just not sure how

Comment: @macro12.  I see. so it will just block user input but not the EDT? Some of the swingworker runs on main thread (i.e Done and process method). But your second comment  is what also confused me

Comment: You have seen the applications? Can you mention one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a chicken/egg if you make it such. You can construct all Swing objects on EDT and then let your `SwingWorker` (or any other thread) govern all updates by instructing EDT to execute them via [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class RudeProgressBar extends JFrame {

    private JButton button;

    public RudeProgressBar() {
        setTitle("Rude Progress Bar");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        button = new JButton("Do teh work");
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(RudeProgressBar.this, true);
                dialog.setTitle("Doing teh work");
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
                dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                dialog.add(progressBar);
                dialog.setSize(100, 100);
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(RudeProgressBar.this);
                MyTask task = new MyTask(dialog);
                task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                            progressBar.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
                        }
                    }
                });
                task.execute();
            }
        });

        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RudeProgressBar().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        private final JDialog dialog;

        public MyTask(JDialog dialog) {
            this.dialog = dialog;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

            int progress = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                setProgress(progress += 20);
            }            

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            dialog.setVisible(false);
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are worried that the `invokeLater` implementation (inside `SwingWorker.doInBackground`) might get executed after `SwingWorker.done`, simply put the code in `done` into another `invokeLater`. By doing this, you queue your `Runnable` implementations for EDT to execute them in certain order. The queuing will happen even if this method is called from EDT itself.

Note that if you take a look at `SwingWorker` implementation, you'll see that it relies on [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to execute `done()` and the `Timer` itself calls `invokeLater`, so calling it inside `done` again amounts to doing nothing. Nothing will be wrong if you do it, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and [SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) instead of swingWorker.

Also, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java) may be useful.

Comment: What do I put in the invokeLater? The display dialog or the worker excution?

Comment: You need to put displaying the dialog in SwingUtilities.invokeLater