# Swing Worker and GUI update

Tags: java, swing, interface, swingworker

i'm new to this community!

I want to ask you something about SwingWorker and its relationship with a GUI.

I know there are some answered questions about SwingWorker, and i've already read a lot of them, taking some helpful advices.

Now i'd like to post some code i wrote for a basic application which counts the number of files and folders from a specified directory.

Since the search could take a lot of time, i want a progress bar to be displayed during the process.
Also, i would like users to have the possibility of stopping count process by clicking a button or simply closing the frame which contains the progress bar.

Here there are some questions on the code posted below:

- The call to execute() method for SwingWorker is the last instruction of WaitingFrame constructor: is there a better place for it?
- The dispose() method for WaitingFrame is called from SwingWorker's done() method, is it correct?
  If a count process is very fast, could the dispose method be called before the waiting frame is actually visible?
  As a result, i would have two open frames...
- Is there a better method to interrupt the process and to manage the message dialogs shown to users?
  I used two boolean variables, valid and interrupted, to achieve my purpose...

And here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
public class CountFiles
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    new CountFilesFrame().setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
class CountFilesFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField field;
    public CountFilesFrame()
    {
        super("Conta File e Cartelle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        JPanel pane=(JPanel)getContentPane();
        pane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,20,5,20));
        JPanel center=new StyledPanel(pane,BorderLayout.CENTER,new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,5,10)),bottom=new StyledPanel(pane,BorderLayout.SOUTH,new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,20,0));
        // Center panel
        center.add(new JLabel("Cartella :"));
        String text="";
        try{
            File folder=new File("../");
            text=folder.exists()?folder.getCanonicalPath():"";
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
        field=new JTextField(text,25);
        center.add(field);
        // JTextArea
        String newLine=System.getProperty("line.separator"),message="Scegliere la cartella da cui far partire la ricerca."+newLine+
        "Sara' contato il numero di file e di cartelle presenti "+newLine+"nella directory inserita e in tutte le sottocartelle";
        JTextArea area=new JTextArea(message);
        area.setEditable(false);
        area.setFont(field.getFont());
        pane.add(area,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // Bottom panel
        bottom.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Cambia Cartella"){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                changeDirectory();
            }
        }));
        bottom.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Inizia ricerca"){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                new WaitingFrame(CountFilesFrame.this);
            }
        }));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public void changeDirectory()
    {
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser(field.getText());
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Cambia Cartella");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        if(chooser.showDialog(this,"Scegli")==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            try
            {
                File selected=chooser.getSelectedFile();
                if(selected.exists())field.setText(selected.getCanonicalPath());
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
    private class WaitingFrame extends JFrame
    {
        private Counter counter;
        public WaitingFrame(CountFilesFrame f)
        {
            super("Ricerca File");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                    stopCounter();
                }
            });
            setResizable(false);
            JPanel pane=(JPanel)getContentPane(),buttonPanel=new StyledPanel(pane,BorderLayout.SOUTH,new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,10));
            JLabel label=new JLabel("Conteggio in corso...",JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,10,0));
            pane.add(label,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            pane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,40,0,40));
            JProgressBar progressBar=new JProgressBar(0,100);
            progressBar.setBorderPainted(false);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            pane.add(progressBar,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Annulla"){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    stopCounter();
                }       
            }));
            while(pane.getSize().width!=pane.getPreferredSize().width)pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);
            (counter=new Counter()).execute();
        }
        public void stopCounter()
        {
            counter.interrupt();
            counter.cancel(true);
        }
        private class Counter extends SwingWorker<Void,Void>
        {
            private boolean valid=true,interrupted=false;
            private int filesNumber=0,foldersNumber=0;
            protected Void doInBackground()
            {
                File folder=new File(field.getText());
                if(!folder.exists()||!folder.isDirectory())valid=false;
                else countFiles(folder);
                return null;
            }
            protected void done()
            {
                dispose();
                if(interrupted)return;
                else if(!valid)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CountFilesFrame.this,"Inserire una cartella valida","Percorso specificato errato",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CountFilesFrame.this,"Sono stati trovati "+(foldersNumber-1)+" cartelle e "+filesNumber+" file","Ricerca completata",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            private void countFiles(File file)
            {
                if(file.isDirectory())
                {
                    foldersNumber++;
                    for(File nested:file.listFiles())countFiles(nested);            
                }
                else filesNumber++;
            }
            public void interrupt()
            {
                interrupted=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
class StyledPanel extends JPanel
{
    public StyledPanel(JPanel parent,String position,LayoutManager layout)
    {
        super(layout);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        parent.add(this,position);
    }
}
```

I posted all the application code, so you can try to compile and run it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: i didn't change interface language, i'm sorry for that. Also, i'm sorry for my bad english...

Comment: *"didn't change interface language"* It does not seem related to the problem, so why would you bother? I note all the class names and attributes are in English. That's handy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The call to execute() method for SwingWorker is the last instruction of WaitingFrame constructor: is there a better place for it?

There is nothing wrong with how you are calling it.

> The dispose() method for WaitingFrame is called from SwingWorker's done() method, is it correct? If a count process is very fast, could the dispose method be called before the waiting frame is actually visible? As a result, i would have two open frames...

It is correct and the situation you describe cannot happen. `SwingWorker.done()` is called on [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via a delayed [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) call and you already called `JFrame.setVisible(true)` before constructing the `SwingWorker` (on EDT).

Instead of [multiple frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice), consider using a dialog, perhaps a modal one if you are attempting to block user input (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37718678/878469)).

> Is there a better method to interrupt the process and to manage the message dialogs shown to users? I used two boolean variables, valid and interrupted, to achieve my purpose...

There certainly is a better way of doing this, considering that your current code is dangerously close to not being thread safe. Consider using an [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of `boolean` if both EDT and swing worker need to access those two members.

You should also check the `interrupted` flag somewhere and exit your file listing loop upon it changing.

You can also wrap any swing code into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` call anywhere inside `SwingWorker.doInBackground()` for fine grained GUI updates. Doing this essentially has the same effect as if `done()` had been invoked but you control when and how many times it is called. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37718678/878469) for a code example. Your own code does this to pass execution from the main thread to EDT inside your `main()` method (the reason for this code pattern is that all swing code must execute on EDT).

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your suggestions!

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your suggestions!

I'll try to apply what you said for the last point.

Regarding dialogs, i have considered the use of a modal dialog, but the call to setVisible wouldn't block process start?
should i call execute() before setVisible() in that case ? I thought it would have been even more risky for what i asked in my second point...

Comment: A modal dialog does block user input after `setVisible(true)` - the call does not return until `setVisible(false)`, but it does not block EDT (events are still processed). You will have to call `execute()` prior to `setVisible()`, or have `doInBackground()` call it for you. Take a look at the linked chicken/egg question. It should address your doubts.

Comment: Note that the second bullet will no longer apply for a modal dialog. It works for `JFrame`, since there is no blocking.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you !! :)

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) this answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: done :) i 've already tried to vote it up, but my reputation is still too low :(