# Load a gif image untill a method execution

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a java method which connects with a server and getting data online.I want to know how do I show a loading gif image until this process end? Tankful if u have a good solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a nice "LOADING..." animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634402/creating-a-nice-loading-animation)

Comment: I can run a loading gif image like this.But i want to do it until the method execution end. can u please explain how could i do it.How can i capture the execution time of a particular method?

Comment: you need to run something in the background or wait for it to execute?

Comment: I need to wait my method untill it execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not capture the exact execution time for a method, so use this logic
This will require:

```
//show loading GIF

//do your job

//hide loading image
```

but in many cases if you are doing a task that may through `Exception` then your progress will remain there although you method is done. So I use this

```
public  void myTask(...) {
    showProgress();
    try {
        //do your job
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    hideProgress();
}

private void showProgress() {
    //progress show code here
}

private void hideProgress() {
   //code here
}
```

You can see the pretty much good progress animation [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531831/pretty-alternative-to-jprogressbar) and add the show progress code and hide progress code on the relevant method.

By making tow methods  one `showProgress` and `hideProgress`, you can simply call them in any method of your class, need not to write code again and again.